# Activity not coming back

Tags: android

I have a method. By using this method i am starting one ListActivity. Here is my source code.

```
private void onCollectionClicked() {
        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FileDialog.class);
        i.putExtra(FileDialog.START_PATH, last_folder);
        startActivityForResult(i, PICK_FILE_CODE);
    }
```

In started ListActivity i have cancel button. If i click this button it should come back to the MainActivity. Here is my source code

```
cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                finish();
            }

        });
```

My problem is ListActivity got killed, But it is not comming back to MainActivity. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Where this coming back then? did you finished the

Comment: There should be a code of `onActivityResult()` method in MainActivity. Please share that code, I believe that, That method contains any `finish();` statement that's why MainActivity gets killed.

Comment: It could be something within your Manifest file such as noHistory

Answer (score 1):

The following example code demonstrates how to trigger and intent with the startActivityForResult() method.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
  Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
  i.putExtra("Value1", "This value one for ActivityTwo ");
  i.putExtra("Value2", "This value two ActivityTwo");
  // Set the request code to any code you like, you can identify the
  // callback via this code
  startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

If you use the startActivityForResult() method then the started activity is called a Sub-Activity.

If the sub-activity is finished it can send data back to its caller via Intent. This is done in the finish() method

```
@Override
public void finish() {
  // Prepare data intent 
  Intent data = new Intent();
  data.putExtra("returnKey1", "Swinging on a star. ");
  data.putExtra("returnKey2", "You could be better then you are. ");
  // Activity finished ok, return the data
  setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
  super.finish();
}
```

Once the sub-activity finishes, the onActivityResult() method in the calling activity is be called.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (data.hasExtra("returnKey1")) {
      Toast.makeText(this, data.getExtras().getString("returnKey1"),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.. This question is wrong. Actually i am killing my MainActivity unknowingly. This is my onPause code.

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //safe close..
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
```

Thanks @Pankaj kumar. Because of your comment, i have checked my onPause method code.

Comment: please dont kill your 1st activity